# Rmarkdown ioslides allowframebreaks alternative

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, bibtex

Is there an equivalent of Beamer's allowframebreaks in Rmarkdown ioslides? This is key for automatically-generated BibTex bibliographies, which spill off the one slide allotted.

The following MWE illustrates the problem I'm trying to solve. The text runs off the page, and I'm looking for a way to automatically break it up into however many slides it takes to comfortably fit the content.

```
---
title: "Allowframebreaks in ioslides?"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

## 

Duis diam ultricies mauris aptent enim velit consequat dolor Vivamus Praesent Nam. Duis Ut convallis leo sodales lacus blandit aliquam penatibus sed netus Ut. Dis id sed fringilla Praesent Suspendisse velit erat imperdiet vehicula ultricies eget adipiscing tellus. Montes maximus semper pulvinar Vivamus mollis non accumsan lacinia scelerisque efficitur ut dictum.

Vivamus euismod ultrices amet dis Aliquam Suspendisse sit faucibus nec nisi aptent orci aliquam. Porta arcu luctus tempor tempor facilisis Phasellus iaculis orci tincidunt faucibus tristique ad Morbi orci. Rhoncus Quisque ipsum Vivamus conubia purus adipiscing bibendum parturient parturient interdum egestas a. Blandit consequat volutpat hendrerit himenaeos Quisque Ut et non neque sagittis tincidunt augue In nascetur.

Nibh euismod consectetur augue feugiat adipiscing turpis sodales purus consequat iaculis diam sollicitudin. Luctus eget mollis pharetra dolor Cum eleifend vitae ligula suscipit Morbi efficitur Duis. Eget Nam eget dis dapibus himenaeos Pellentesque sed fermentum varius Lorem Donec. Malesuada nostra litora ante augue ligula mollis elementum Pellentesque at sociosqu lobortis sociis.

Taciti imperdiet est habitant mus in et nulla tincidunt venenatis Class Sed. Egestas ad Maecenas turpis interdum nulla enim felis Integer tortor nascetur ullamcorper cursus Curabitur. Nascetur auctor Vestibulum tincidunt augue efficitur justo posuere dictum nunc auctor pellentesque ex facilisis. Convallis montes Lorem aptent elementum consectetur enim non ante nascetur sit nulla. Posuere consequat rutrum Aenean libero Aliquam laoreet consectetur Cras ipsum Donec eget Morbi. Consectetur vehicula sociosqu massa Lorem mollis Duis fames hendrerit Praesent dignissim Proin enim.

Odio at Nam placerat parturient euismod Morbi facilisis enim Phasellus Maecenas aliquam ultrices condimentum. Sem metus massa lacinia rutrum pulvinar vel a eu purus scelerisque suscipit. Feugiat mi natoque imperdiet lectus egestas mi Etiam ullamcorper Vestibulum sit euismod. Vestibulum mus Praesent eleifend faucibus torquent vitae Etiam fermentum Nullam Cras et interdum amet. Fringilla tortor aptent Cum senectus Quisque auctor nunc nascetur arcu nec Lorem.
```

Comment: Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38260799/references-page-truncated-in-rmarkdown-ioslides-presentation) with an alternative solution.

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, this question is a bit of a duplicate.  One answer is here:

[References page truncated in RMarkdown ioslides presentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38260799/references-page-truncated-in-rmarkdown-ioslides-presentation/38294541#38294541)

To quote the answer:

> This isn't exactly what you're asking for, but it might be the best you can do.  Insert the following inline CSS at the end of your document (i.e. just before where the references will be inserted), and instead of truncating them, it will add a scroll bar (the first part) and suppress the page number (the second part).

```
<style>
slides > slide { overflow: scroll; }
slides > slide:not(.nobackground):after {
content: '';
}
</style>
```

> You won't be able to see all references at once, but at least you can scroll through them.  (You can add this after the header on any long slide for the same effect.)

Original answer posted by [user2554330](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2554330/user2554330)

Comment: I had misread the question and have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what to do here -- if the question is an exact duplicate then you should vote to close as duplicate, or if you don't have enough reputation then you should leave a comment ... on the other hand, I'm not sure how that interacts with bounties (what should magically happen there is that the original answerer should get most of the credit and you should get a bit of credit for pointing out the duplicate). I'm not hopeful, but I'm hoping someone else will come up with a solution that actually breaks the element into more than one slide ...

Comment: I second Ben Bolker. Thanks for the answer. I don't yet believe my question was originally a duplicate, though. I asked mine in 2015, and the one linked at the top of the answer was posted in 2016.