# References page truncated in RMarkdown ioslides presentation

Tags: knitr, r-markdown, ioslides

I prepare a ioslides presentation in RMarkdown via RStudio. As the presentation contains a lot of references they are truncated:
[image]
With `{.allowframebraks}`there seems to be a quick solution for `beamer` presentations as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35677857/references-truncated-in-beamer-presentation-prepared-in-knitr-rmarkdown) shows.
Is there one for ioslides, too?

Comment: I cannot comment due to my tiny rep. I'm finding this accepted answer works but is not compatible with 'link-citations: yes', as clicking in-text citation links result in the presentation loading in a new window/tab at the top page.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This isn't exactly what you're asking for, but it might be the best you can do.  Insert the following inline CSS at the end of your document (i.e. just before where the references will be inserted), and instead of truncating them, it will add a scroll bar (the first part) and suppress the page number (the second part).

```
<style>
slides > slide { overflow: scroll; }
slides > slide:not(.nobackground):after {
  content: '';
}
</style>
```

You won't be able to see all references at once, but at least you can scroll through them.  (You can add this after the header on any long slide for the same effect.)

Edited to add:

To suppress the logo, this should work:

```
<style>
slides > slide:not(.nobackground):before {
  background: none;
}
</style>
```

Generally to figure things like this out, use Firefox (or another browser?), point at the thing of interest, right click and choose Inspect Element.  That will tell you where it came from, and you might be able to guess how to suppress it.

Comment: that ist great! Thank you. Do you futhermore have an idea how to supress the Logo for this page?

Comment: Thank's again for the edited hint. Meanwhile I figured some issues out using the Firefox "Inspect Element" function. What didn't get to work is a workaround to apply the suppression of the logo for only one slide using the #id selectro in css. Any ideas?

Comment: That's going beyond my "expertise".  You should probably post a new question and someone else might get it.